# Complex symmetric matrices are normal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

In the taxonomy at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_matrices, it says that complex symmetric matrices are normal. For real symmetric matrices, you can prove that they are hermitian hence normal.

How would you prove the normality for a complex symmetric matrix ?

Comment: Complex symmetric matrices are not (necessarily) normal (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23629/non-diagonalizable-complex-symmetric-matrix/23631 for a counterexample) and I couldn't find this claimed statement in the wiki page.

Comment: @levap, there's a little diagram at that wiki page. If you click on it so it becomes big enough to read, you'll find it shows real symmetric matrices included in symmetric matrices, and those included in normal matrices. But of course you're right, complex symmetric matrices are not necessarily normal.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Oops, sorry, I completely missed the diagram.

Comment: I will notify the Wikipedia talk page. Thank you for the link to the counter-example.